# Telegram add member to channel by bot api

Tags: php, python, api, bots, telegram

I have seen this question, but unfortunately no one answered:
[How to add user to my telegram channel by telegram api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33734536/how-to-add-user-to-my-telegram-channel-by-telegram-api)

I have created a bot and a channel in telegram. Then I added the bot to channel's administrators. How can I add members to channel by my bot APIs?!
Programming languages: PHP, Python, C++:Qt, Java, C# (every of them or any library)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't do anything except posting to channel via bot using Telegram Bot API.

Hovewer, you may take a look at [Telegram-CLI Bot interface](https://github.com/yagop/telegram-bot), which uses normal user accounts to make them bots.