# Is it possible to programmatically approve users only to post to a channel on Telegram?

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, node-telegram-bot-api

I want to create a group dynamic with anonymity on Telegram. I get that you can use any username and be anonymous on telegram but if you are on someone’s contact list, they can always message you - even if you change your username. So you cannot be anonymous to someone who *already* knows you on a telegram group, for example.

I want to enable anonymity among contacts. I understand that there is not way to do this today. Correct?

My goal is to have a telegram private channel that is allocated to a particular school - say Harvard.edu and anyone can join, but only users who have validated their email can participate by posting messages to the channel. Since an ordinary user cannot post messages to the channel, the posting will be done through a bot.

So it goes like this:

- Person tries to post new message to a bot,
- bot verifies user
- bot relays post to the channel.

This way it looks like there are replies on the channel but no one knows who exactly posted the replies.

Is anyone doing anything like this?

For a “reply” things get more complicated because we need to have some sort of inline button after every posting that embeds a link to the bot along with the message ID so that a response is not shown as a new message but as a conversational reply.

Does the api support this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`I understand that there is not way to do this today. Correct?`

**Answer : Yes , There is no way for now**
 Unfortunately you **can't** add member to your channel via Telegram's bot except CLI Telegram Bots. In this case you can search on Github/Gitlab for it. [Here](https://github.com/yagop/telegram-bot) is an example. Beside I already found a question like your question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34872139/7903663)

Anyway let's assume you could make an CLI bot. The point is you should set permission for your channel admins as you can see in the below picture.

[image]

as you know you should just let user to "Post messages".

[image]